# CSS spacing bottom on a relative position div with auto height

Tags: css, height, spacing, css-position

I'm trying to add space at bottom of an div with relative position and auto height. Can someone point me on the right way?

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/Pdz3g/

I tryed to use in #content:

```
margin-bottom: 20px;
```

But is useless when top rule is defined.

and:

```
bottom: 20px;
```

For some reazon dosn't work too.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to see the 4 sides of `#content ` into the viewport with even some room (20px) below it?

Comment: Why are you using relative positioning to begin with?

Comment: @Diodeus: Im wokring on a website the container has a background image and I need to move the content 500 pixels from top. If i use absolute position has the same problem, when top property is set margin-bottom dosn't work.

Comment: @FelipeAls want to see the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative positioning will allow you to move an element outside the viewport depending on the displacement, its height and how close it is from one of the side of the viewport, so you can't be sure to keep `#content` entirely visible...

See for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pdz3g/1/ where it works because the height is known, due to `min-height`. If the block grow vertically, its bottom side will again be hidden outside of the viewport.

If you want more control over this element then don't use relative positioning...

Comment: But if i pass more than 250px of min-height http://jsfiddle.net/Pdz3g/2/ dosn't works.

Comment: I tryed this, add `margin-bottom: 175%;` to #content, sems than works but i need a integer value.

Comment: Solved it, I used `margin-top` and dont add child #content to #container